# select tag onchange does not execute, function failure: Uncaught ReferenceError: ... is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm pretty new to js.
I want to execute the function buildChart when the select value changes.

But I get the following error all the time.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: buildChart is not defined
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?

Thank you very much in advance! You would be a great help!!

My JS function is as follows:

```
class GetData {

    getCanvasUrl(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-url")
    }

    getDropdownValue() {
        return document.getElementById("dropdown-pp").value;
    }

    async fetchData(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return await response.json();
    }
}

const getData = new GetData();

function buildChart() {
    let dropdownValue = getData.getDropdownValue();
    if (dropdownValue === "All Generations") {
        console.log("All Generations")
    } else {
        console.log("other")
    }
}

buildChart();
```

My HTML follows here:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<script rel="script" type="module" src="{% static 'js/productionplan/productionplan.js' %}" defer></script>
{% endblock head %}


{% block body %}
<select id="dropdown-pp" onchange="buildChart();" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: An inline listener requires everything referred in it being defined in the global scope. Is `buildChart` in the global scope? Or is it defined in a module, when it's not in the global scope.

Comment: Yes it should, but is it? Is `buildChart` defined in the script which is loaded in a tag having `type="module"` attribute? If that's the case, the `buildChart` is not in the global scope, it is in the namespace the module creates. Don't use inline listeners with modules, they don't work. Attach the events in the script using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Hello Teemu thanks for your help.
I uploaded my complete js file.
Yes it is defined in the script on the head.

Comment: @Teemu ,
I changed `type="module"` to `type="application/javascript"` but now get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: You have an idea how to solve this one?

Comment: Again: Don't use inline listeners, attach the events in a script using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), that's the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Teemu I was able to solve the problem.
The magic is in the last line.

Here is my code:

```
import  { stackedBar } from '../charts.js'

stackedBar("#bar-chart");


class GetData {

    getCanvasUrl(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-url")
    }

    getDropdownValue() {
        return document.getElementById("dropdown-pp").value;
    }

    async fetchData(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return await response.json();
    }
}

const getData = new GetData();

function buildChart() {
    let dropdownValue = getData.getDropdownValue();
    if (dropdownValue === "All Generations") {
        console.log("All Generations")
    } else {
        console.log("other")
    }
}

document.getElementById("dropdown-pp").addEventListener("change", buildChart);
```

When the select tag with dropdown-pp changes the function buildChart is called.

Thanks a lot Teemu!!!!!!!!!!!